# Auto calculation VBA excel

Tags: excel, user-defined-functions, calculated-field, vba

When you create a custom-user defined function in VBA that can be used as a regular spreadsheet function, I can't seem to stop it from auto calculating during, before, and after run time.

The data is in a table format and auto populates when adding extra rows. When I set application.calculation to xlmanual, the macro still iterates over each row to ensure that the user defined function is calculating - but there doesn't seem to be a way to pause that and significantly decrease runtime. Why is it that every row  in a table with a custom-user defined function keeps getting triggered when something interacts with it?

Another potential symptom  - what is what's even more problematic is that when I click on a cell(when the macro isn't running) containing a formula, each and every row still auto calculates even when set on manual.

This seems to be a bug, or maybe the downside of using a table list object. Any way around this?

Let me know if I explained the question well, or I can continue to revise this for a productive answer.

Comment: How do you know it is calculating "each and every row"? Can you post your code?

Comment: I assume your UDF is not tagged `Volatile`?  That ensures it is always recalculating.  The bit about "still auto calculates when set on manual" does not sound correct.  Do you have other code running that would call for recalculations?  Also, when you "click on a cell" does that just mean selection or does it mean clicking and editing?  If editing, that will definitely redo the formula.  If it's just selection, do you have a `SelectionChange` event running?